# OpenTok message: "OT.Subscriber is not connected cannot getStats", name: "OT_NOT_CONNECTED"

Tags: opentok

I am getting error
OT.Subscriber is not connected cannot getStats
code: 1015
message: "OT.Subscriber is not connected cannot getStats"
name: "OT_NOT_CONNECTED

I am subscribing like this when the scream is created.
this.session.subscribe(event.stream, null, subscriberOptions, error => {})